# Issue while executing stored procedure which consists both update and insert statements

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am new to PLSQL and I am trying to execute this stored procedure shown here.

This stored procedure will check for a particular row and based on the count update the table or insert. But I am getting below errors as a whole.

> 31/18   PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
>   31/1    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   37/26   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   36/1    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I tried my best to solve them. Could you please help in solving the issue?

This is the procedure I have written for this task:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LPR_LP_TEST.SP_PTMS_NOTES
(
p_app_lse_s     IN mjl.app_lse_s%TYPE,
p_dt_ent_s      IN mjl.dt_ent_s%TYPE,
p_note_type_s   IN mjl.note_type_s%TYPE,
p_prcs_c        IN mjl.prcs_c%TYPE,
p_prio_c        IN mjl.prio_c%TYPE,
p_note_title_s  IN mjl.note_title_s%TYPE,
p_info1_s       IN mjl.info1_s%TYPE,
p_info2_s       IN mjl.info2_s%TYPE
)
AS
v_rowcount_i     number;
v_lien_date    mjl.info1_s%TYPE;
--v_lien_date      NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG.LIEN_DT%TYPE;
v_asst_amount    mjl.info2_s%TYPE;

BEGIN
app_lse_s:=trim(app_lse_s);
dbms_output.put_line(app_lse_s);

select LIEN_DT,ASES_PRT_1_AM 
INTO v_lien_date,v_asst_amount
from NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG
where LSE_ID ='&2';

select count(*) into v_rowcount_i from MJL where trim(app_lse_s) ='&2';

if v_rowcount_i = 0 then
begin
Insert into MJL
('app_lse_s','dt_ent_s','note_type_s','prcs_c','prio_c','note_title_s','info
1_s','Info2_s') 
values ('&2','sysdate','SPPT','Y','1','Property Tax 
Assessment','v_lien_date','v_asst_amount');
end;
else
begin
update mjl
set dt_ent_s = 'sysdate' and note_type_s = 'SPPT' and prcs_c = 'Y' and 
prio_c = '1' and note_title_s = 'Property Tax Assessment' and info1_s = 
'v_lien_date' and Info2_s = 'v_asst_amount'
where trim(app_lse_s) = '&2';
end;
end if;
commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: You keep referencing `'&2'`, but this is a procedure. If you're expecting to replace `&2` with a value, you should be using a parameter. Also, what's with `app_lse_s:=trim(app_lse_s);` when you don't have a variable of that name declared? Additionally, you don't need the extra begin/end around the update and inserts - which should probably be a single MERGE statement! Finally, you've enclosed the column names in your insert statement in single quotes; either there should be no quotes (columns are case insensitive) or double-quotes (columns are case sensitive) around them.

Comment: Thanks @Boneist for the valuable suggestions. "&2" i am entering the value while executing the procedure. Now i am getting the below error in the update statement .
"ERROR line 35, col 26, ending_line 35, ending_col 28, Found 'and', Expecting: ;   -or-   LOG   -or-   RETURN  RETURNING   -or-   WHERE   -or-   ,   -or-   +  -  ||   -or-   *  /  MOD  REM   -or-   **   -or-   (  (+)  AT  DAY  MULTISET  YEAR" . I am not sure where i am missing. Could you please help me on this one?

Comment: See point 2 in my answer below. As for `"&2" i am entering the value while executing the procedure` - you can do that by passing the value in as a parameter, e.g. `begin lpr_lp_test.sp_ptms_notes(p_app_lse_s => '123', ....); end; /`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your procedure should look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LPR_LP_TEST.SP_PTMS_NOTES
(
p_app_lse_s     IN mjl.app_lse_s%TYPE,
p_dt_ent_s      IN mjl.dt_ent_s%TYPE,
p_note_type_s   IN mjl.note_type_s%TYPE,
p_prcs_c        IN mjl.prcs_c%TYPE,
p_prio_c        IN mjl.prio_c%TYPE,
p_note_title_s  IN mjl.note_title_s%TYPE,
p_info1_s       IN mjl.info1_s%TYPE,
p_info2_s       IN mjl.info2_s%TYPE
)
AS
  v_rowcount_i   number;
  v_lien_date    mjl.info1_s%TYPE;
  --v_lien_date    NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG.LIEN_DT%TYPE;
  v_asst_amount  mjl.info2_s%TYPE;
  v_app_lse_s    mjl.app_lse_s%TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_app_lse_s := trim(p_app_lse_s);

  -- I hope this dbms_output line is for temporary debug purposes only
  -- and will be removed in the production version!
  dbms_output.put_line(app_lse_s);

  merge into mjl tgt
    using (select lse_s app_lse_s,
                  sysdate dt_ent_s,
                  'SPPT' note_type_s,
                  'Y' prcs_c,
                  '1' prio_c,
                  'Property Tax Assessment' note_title_s,
                  lien_dt info1_s,
                  ases_prt_1_am info2_s
           from   nmac_ptms_notebk_sg
           where  lse_id = v_app_lse_s) src
      on (tgt.app_lse_s = src.app_lse_s)
  when matched then
    update set tgt.dt_ent_s = src.dt_ent_s,
               tgt.note_title_s = src.note_title_s,
               tgt.info1_s = src.info1_s,
               tgt.info2_s = src.info2_s
    where tgt.dt_end_s != src.dt_ent_s
    or    tgt.note_title_s != src.note_title_s
    or    tgt.info1_s != src.info1_s
    or    tgt.info2_s != src.info2_s
  when not matched then
    insert (tgt.app_lse_s,
            tgt.dt_ent_s,
            tgt.note_type_s,
            tgt.prcs_c,
            tgt.prio_c,
            tgt.note_title_s,
            tgt.info1_s,
            tgt.info2_s)
    values (src.app_lse_s,
            src.dt_ent_s,
            src.note_type_s,
            src.prcs_c,
            src.prio_c,
            src.note_title_s,
            src.info1_s,
            src.info2_s);

  commit;
end;
/
```

Things for you to note about your procedure and what I did to come up with the above procedure:

1. You have a tendency to enclose everything in single quotes. Single quotes are used to declare something as a string, i.e. `some_variable := 'string value'`. If you put single quotes around something that is actually an identifier, you are really telling Oracle to treat it as a string - which will result in all sorts of errors! The only time you should use quotes around an identifier is when the identifier's name is case sensitive, and you should use double-quotes. E.g. `select * from "lower_case_tablename"`. (N.B. I say "should" here, but that's a guideline; you can use double-quotes around non-case-sensitive identifier names, but if you do so, the name should be in uppercase - i.e. `select * from "DUAL";`).
2. Your update statement syntax was incorrect - updates to several columns in a single statement are separated by commas, not `and`s.
3. The `begin`s and `ends` around your insert and update statements are unnecessary.
4. If you're going to have an implicit cursor (i.e. the `select ... into <variable list> from ...` in the procedure body), you need to make sure you handle the NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS exceptions that might be thrown up.
5. I set up a variable to store the trimmed value passed in by the parameter p_app_lse_s - I assume that this is what you meant to do? I also replaced all the calls to '&2' with the variable.
6. If you need to do an upsert (i.e. insert if the row doesn't already exist, otherwise update) then consider a MERGE statement. If you absolutely must keep them separate, then don't check for the existence of the row first; do the insert first and check for a DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX error - then do the update in the exception handler. Alternatively, do the update first and check SQL%ROWCOUNT to see if rows were amended and if not, then do the insert. A MERGE is preferable, though, since it means there's no opportunity for someone to insert a row in a different session in the split second it takes the database to go between the two statements.
7. By using a MERGE statement, I was able to incorporate all your logic into a single SQL statement, which makes your procedure simpler and easier to debug. For a start, I'm betting the other parameters in your procedure need to be used inside the procedure; it's easy to update the source query in the merge statement to replace the hardcoded values with the parameter names! I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do.
8. If you're getting the info1_s and info2_s values from the nmac_ptms_notebk_sg, do you really need the p_info1_s and p_info2_s parameters? They wouldn't seem to be needed, IMHO.

Finally, this procedure is doing the work a single app_lse_s at a time. If your database processing is OLTP, that's fine. If it's doing batch processing, and your code looks something like the following pseudo-code:

```
for each row in <this cursor>
loop
  execute the lpr_lp_test.sp_ptms_notes procedure
end loop
```

then you'd be better off merging the sp_ptms_notes procedure into the calling procedure and doing the work in a single MERGE statement.

---

ETA: If you have a staging table (which could be an external table or a Global Temporary Table (GTT) or even a normal heap table) that contains the data you want to load into your database, then your merge statement would become something like:

```
  merge into mjl tgt
    using (select trim(st.app_lse_s) app_lse_s,
                  sysdate dt_ent_s,
                  'SPPT' note_type_s,
                  'Y' prcs_c,
                  '1' prio_c,
                  'Property Tax Assessment' note_title_s,
                  npns.lien_dt info1_s,
                  npns.ases_prt_1_am info2_s
           from   staging_table st
                  inner join nmac_ptms_notebk_sg npns-- maybe left outer join?
                    on trim(st.app_lse_s) = npns.lse_s) src
      on (tgt.app_lse_s = src.app_lse_s)
  when matched then
    update set tgt.dt_ent_s = src.dt_ent_s,
               tgt.note_title_s = src.note_title_s,
               tgt.info1_s = src.info1_s,
               tgt.info2_s = src.info2_s
    where tgt.dt_end_s != src.dt_ent_s
    or    tgt.note_title_s != src.note_title_s
    or    tgt.info1_s != src.info1_s
    or    tgt.info2_s != src.info2_s
  when not matched then
    insert (tgt.app_lse_s,
            tgt.dt_ent_s,
            tgt.note_type_s,
            tgt.prcs_c,
            tgt.prio_c,
            tgt.note_title_s,
            tgt.info1_s,
            tgt.info2_s)
    values (src.app_lse_s,
            src.dt_ent_s,
            src.note_type_s,
            src.prcs_c,
            src.prio_c,
            src.note_title_s,
            src.info1_s,
            src.info2_s);
```

You can see that I've joined the nmac_ptms_notebk_sg table to the staging table, and used that to generate the set of data that needs to be merged into your mjl table. If your file/staging table also contains information for the other columns (dt_ent_s, note_type_s, etc) then you can replace the hardcoded values with the columns from the staging table.

Comment: I am getting the bunch of  lse_id from a text file and trying to pass them as a parameter in a shell script in a loop to the stored procedure. How this can be dealt?

Comment: If the file is visible to the database (i.e. the database process owner) then you could use an external table to expose the file as a table in the database. Otherwise there's SQL*Loader, or the row-by-row process you have now. Personally, I'd get the data from the file into a staging table and then run a single merge statement to load the data into the main table.

Comment: It's a text file coming from a vendor. Through Shell scripting i am capturing only the lse_id column and running the loop in script to pass this a parameter to check in the database to insert or update in the mjl table. For this I am internally calling this Stored procedure in the shell script. Can we do it in that way?

Comment: Yes, of course you can, although it's not likely to be the fastest way of doing it. I would still load the ids into a staging table and then use that table in a single merge statement to update the mjl table. Think of this: you have a bath full of water, a spoon and a jug. Which is the fastest way of emptying the bath? Your method is the equivalent of using a spoon; mine is the equivalent of pulling the bathplug out!

Comment: When I am executing the stored procedure I am getting the below error "ORA-00001: unique constraint (LPR_LP_TEST.MJL_IDX0) violated". In the MJL table they have created a Unique index on app_lse_s and dt_ent_s. Do i still need to use dt_ent_s in the update statement?


when matched then
    update set tgt.dt_ent_s = src.dt_ent_s,
               tgt.note_title_s = src.note_title_s,
               tgt.info1_s = src.info1_s,
               tgt.info2_s = src.info2_s
    where tgt.dt_end_s != src.dt_ent_s
    or    tgt.note_title_s != src.note_title_s

Comment: You'd need to add the dt_ent column into the join between the tgt table and the src subquery. You'd also need to remove it from the update part.

Comment: I am not going to use the staging table in this scenario. How to handle this in the first procedure which you have provided it to me? It will be great for me...

Comment: You'd need to work out what information you need to pass in to the procedure (is it just the id that you're getting from the file?) and then add/remove the parameters as necessary. You'd then have to adjust the columns in the src subquery as necessary. If you need further help, please raise a new question, giving details of your tables, sample data in the tables and file and a) the procedure you've tried to get working and b) the output you're expecting to see.

Comment: I have raised a new question with sample data and table details.Here is the link for this. It will be great if you have a look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057006/sample-data-issue-while-executing-stored-procedure-which-consists-both-update

Comment: I have raised another new question. Could toy please have a look at it again to see if i am missing something there?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057006/sample-data-issue-while-executing-stored-procedure-which-consists-both-update