# Sample data - "Issue while executing stored procedure which consists both update and insert statements"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Below are the sample table and file details for the question which I have asked on "Issue while executing stored procedure which consists both update and insert statements". Below are the steps I am following before executing the Procedure.

1. I will get a file from the Vendor which contains the data in the below format.

   ```
   6437,,01/01/2017,3483.92,,
   14081,,01/01/2017,8444.23,,
   ```
2. I am loading these data to the table `NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG`. In the above file 1st column will be the asset.
3. I am updating the table with extra column with name `lse_id` with respect to that asset. Now the `NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG` table will have the data in the below format.

   ```
   LSE_ID  AST_ID PRPRTY_TAX_DDCTN_CD LIEN_DT    ASES_PRT_1_AM ASES_PRT_2_AM
   5868087 5049   Null                01-01-2017 3693.3        NULL
   ```
4. Now my procedure will start. In my procedure the logic should be in a way I need to take the `lse_id` from `NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG` and compare the same in `MJL` table (here `lse_id = app_lse_s`). Below is the structure for `MJL` table.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE LPR_LP_TEST.MJL
   (
     APP_LSE_S     CHAR(10 BYTE)                   NOT NULL,
     DT_ENT_S      TIMESTAMP(3)                    NOT NULL, 
     DT_FOL_S      TIMESTAMP(3),
     NOTE_TYPE_S   CHAR(4 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
     PRCS_C        CHAR(1 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
     PRIO_C        CHAR(1 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
     FROM_S        CHAR(3 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
     TO_S          CHAR(3 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
     NOTE_TITLE_S  VARCHAR2(41 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
     INFO_S        VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     STAMP_L       NUMBER(10)                      NOT NULL,
     PRIVATE_C     CHAR(1 BYTE),
     LSE_ACC_C     CHAR(1 BYTE),
     COL_STAT_S    CHAR(4 BYTE),
     INFO1_S       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
     INFO2_S       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
     INFO3_S       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
     INFO4_S       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
     NTBK_RSN_S    CHAR(4 BYTE)
   )
   TABLESPACE LPR_LP_TEST
   PCTUSED    0
   PCTFREE    25
   INITRANS   1
   MAXTRANS   255
   STORAGE    (
       INITIAL          64K
       NEXT             1M
       MINEXTENTS       1
       MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
       PCTINCREASE      0
       BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
   )
   LOGGING 
   NOCOMPRESS 
   NOCACHE
   NOPARALLEL
   MONITORING;

   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX LPR_LP_TEST.MJL_IDX0 ON LPR_LP_TEST.MJL
   (APP_LSE_S, DT_ENT_S)
   LOGGING
   TABLESPACE LPR_LP_TEST
   PCTFREE    10
   INITRANS   2
   MAXTRANS   255
   STORAGE    (
       INITIAL          64K
       NEXT             1M
       MINEXTENTS       1
       MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
       PCTINCREASE      0
       BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
   )
   NOPARALLEL;

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LPR_LP_TEST."MT_MJL_AIUD" 
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mjl
   BEGIN
   mpkg_trig_mjl.mp_mjl_aiud;
   END mt_mjl_aiud;
   / 

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LPR_LP_TEST."MT_MJL_AIUDR" 
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mjl FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   mpkg_trig_mjl.mp_mjl_aiudr (INSERTING, UPDATING, DELETING,
               :NEW.app_lse_s, :NEW.prcs_c, :NEW.note_type_s,
               :OLD.app_lse_s, :OLD.prcs_c, :OLD.note_type_s);
   END mt_mjl_aiudr;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LPR_LP_TEST."MT_MJL_BIUD" 
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mjl
   BEGIN
   mpkg_trig_mjl.mp_mjl_biud;
   END mt_mjl_biud;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LPR_LP_TEST."MT_MJL_OBIUR" 
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mjl FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN
       :NEW.stamp_l := mpkg_util.mp_time_ticker;
   ELSE
       IF :OLD.stamp_l > 999999990 THEN
           :NEW.stamp_l := 1;
       ELSE
           :NEW.stamp_l := :OLD.stamp_l + 1;
       END IF;
   END IF;
   END mt_mjl_obiur;
   /
   ```
5. Below is the procedure I am using which you have provided in previous post and it is almost working good for me.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LPR_LP_TEST.SP_PTMS_NOTES
      (
      p_app_lse_s     IN mjl.app_lse_s%TYPE,
      --p_dt_ent_s      IN mjl.dt_ent_s%TYPE,
      --p_note_type_s   IN mjl.note_type_s%TYPE,
      --p_prcs_c        IN mjl.prcs_c%TYPE,
      --p_prio_c        IN mjl.prio_c%TYPE,
      --p_note_title_s  IN mjl.note_title_s%TYPE,
      --p_info1_s       IN mjl.info1_s%TYPE,
      --p_info2_s       IN mjl.info2_s%TYPE
      )
      AS
      --v_rowcount_i   number;
      --v_lien_date    mjl.info1_s%TYPE;
      --v_lien_date    NMAC_PTMS_NOTEBK_SG.LIEN_DT%TYPE;
      --v_asst_amount  mjl.info2_s%TYPE;
      v_app_lse_s    mjl.app_lse_s%TYPE;
BEGIN
      v_app_lse_s := trim(p_app_lse_s);

      -- I hope this dbms_output line is for temporary debug purposes only
      -- and will be removed in the production version!
      dbms_output.put_line(app_lse_s);

      merge into mjl tgt
      using (select lse_s app_lse_s,
                    sysdate dt_ent_s,
                    'SPPT' note_type_s,
                    'Y' prcs_c,
                    '1' prio_c,
                    'Property Tax Assessment' note_title_s,
                    lien_dt info1_s,
                    ases_prt_1_am info2_s
             from   nmac_ptms_notebk_sg
             where  lse_id = v_app_lse_s) src
      on (trim(tgt.app_lse_s) = trim(src.app_lse_s))
        -- and tgt.dt_ent_s = src.dt_ent_s) 
      when matched then
      update set --tgt.dt_ent_s = src.dt_ent_s,
                 tgt.note_title_s = src.note_title_s,
                 tgt.info1_s = src.info1_s,
                 tgt.info2_s = src.info2_s
      where --tgt.dt_ent_s != src.dt_ent_s
         tgt.note_title_s != src.note_title_s
      or    tgt.info1_s != src.info1_s
      or    tgt.info2_s != src.info2_s
      when not matched then
      insert (tgt.app_lse_s,
              tgt.dt_ent_s,
              tgt.note_type_s,
              tgt.prcs_c,
              tgt.prio_c,
              tgt.from_s,
              tgt.to_s,
              tgt.note_title_s,
              tgt.info1_s,
              tgt.info2_s)
      values (src.app_lse_s,
              src.dt_ent_s,
              src.note_type_s,
              src.prcs_c,
              src.prio_c,
              src.from_s,
              src.to_s,
              src.note_title_s,
              src.info1_s,
              src.info2_s);

      commit;
end;
```

6. Now the logic should be I need to pass `lse_id` from the file which I 
   have already saved to the procedure.
7. If the `lse_id` which I am passing is matching with the `app_lse_s` in 
   the `mjl` table then I need to update that row and some of the harcoded 
   fields which I am doing it correclty.
8. If the `lse_id` is not matching then I have to insert a new row for that 
   lease and the hardcoded fields.
9. The issue which I am facing is the `dt_ent_s` in the `mjl` table is a 
   unique constraint.

Please let me know if the above is making any sense to you...

Comment: Can you edit the question by format code of the procedure?

Comment: @Nitish. I tried to change the format code of the procedure. Bit it is not reflecting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The issue which I am facing is the dt_ent_s in the mjl table is a unique constraint."

Actually it's not, it's part of a compound unique key. So really your ON clause should match on

```
on (tgt.app_lse_s  = src.app_lse_s
    and tgt.dt_ent_s = src.dt_ent_s)
```

Incidentally, the use of `trim()` in the ON clause is worrying, especially `trim(tgt.app_lse_s)`. If you're inserting values with trailing or leading spaces your "unique key" will produce multiple hits when you trim them.  You should trim the spaces when you load the data from the file and insert trimmed values in your table.

---

> "ORA-00001: unique constraint (LPR_LP_TEST.MJL_IDX0) violated"

`MJL_IDX0` must me a unique index. That means you need to include its columns in any consideration of unique records.

Clearly there is a difference between your straight INSERT logic and your MERGE INSERT logic. You need to compare the two statements and figure out what the difference is.

Comment: I am getting one more error here. While inserting it is throwing ORA-00001: unique constraint (LPR_LP_TEST.MJL_IDX0) violated. I checked the MJL table and there is an index created for this. My issue is when i try to insert the record using normal insert statement it worked but not in the merge statement. Could you please help me on this one?

Comment: now i am getting below error while executing this procedure. Could you please check on this one.

    03494
    BEGIN SP_PTMS_NOTES('03494'); END;

    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
    ORA-06512: at "LPR_LP_TEST.SP_PTMS_NOTES", line 18 
    ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Please read my answer to [a question on ORA-30926](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44635446/146325). If that doesn't help you solve your problem you will need to ask a new question, posting your MERGE statement and a small set of sample data which reproduces the problem.