# Oracle sql MERGE INTO with a single where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-merge

I have the following SQL code (this is how much I've got so far):

```
 MERGE INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE_1 table1 USING
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT table2.column1, 
            view1.column2
     FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE_2 table2
     LEFT JOIN SCHEMA2.VIEW_1 view1
     ON table2.column2 = view1.column3

    ) t2 ON (table1.column3 = t2.column1 )

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET table1.column4 = t2.column2;
```

The following is the definition of VIEW_1 :

```
    CREATE VIEW SCHEMA_2.VIEW_1
AS (SELECT 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_1.COLUMN_1, 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2.COLUMN_1,
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2.COLUMN_2,
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2.COLUMN_3,
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_5.COLUMN_1, 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_6.COLUMN_1, 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_6.COLUMN_2,
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_6.COLUMN_3,
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_6.COLUMN_4, 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_7.COLUMN_1, 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_7.COLUMN_2, 
SCHEMA_2.TABLE_8.COLUMN_1 
FROM SCHEMA_2.TABLE_1
INNER JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2
ON SCHEMA_2.TABLE_1.COLUMN_1 = SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2.COLUMN_2 
INNER JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_5
ON SCHEMA_2.TABLE_1.COLUMN_4 = SCHEMA_2.TABLE_5.COLUMN_3
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_6
ON SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2.COLUMN_2 = SCHEMA_2.TABLE_6.COLUMN_4
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_7
ON SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2.COLUMN_1 = SCHEMA_2.TABLE_8.COLUMN_5
);
```

But I'm getting the below error message:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
```

What causes the error? Where to change in the code to make it work?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Is `view1` by any chance a view based on `table1`?

Comment: can you please post definition of `view_1`

Comment: it's a view whose tables are all in schema2

Comment: "It's in SCHEMA2" doesn't automatically mean "doesn't have nothing in common". The view, in SCHEMA2, may still reference tables from SCHEMA1. Besides, your credibility is very low, since you posted the same question three times in the past 8 hours, and at least once you were EXPLICITLY using the target table in the USING clause.

Comment: yes, I did, but I removed form the clauses anything related to schema1 and still didnt work so . . .

Comment: Less you show less chance others solve your problem. It is not possible to find error without all pieces. Please provide code of view and if view uses another view one need also that one and so on.

Comment: @Kacper Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this error is returned, not only when the USING clause returns more than one row for a row in the MATCH table, but also frequently when it cannot be *sure* that only one row will be returned (even if there are no actual cases of multiple rows being returned).  To force the parser to accept the query in cases like this, I usually resort to using a GROUP BY on the MATCH..ON column(s).

```
MERGE INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE_1 table1 USING
(
 SELECT table2.column1, 
        MAX(view1.column2) as column2
 FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE_2 table2
 LEFT JOIN SCHEMA2.VIEW_1 view1
 ON table2.column2 = view1.column3
 GROUP BY table2.column1
) t2 ON (table1.column3 = t2.column1 )

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET table1.column4 = t2.column2;
```

Comment: [PLUS ONE] Perfect! This made it work, saved my life!

Comment: Suppressing `ORA-30926` is not the same thing as making the query work. Why should `max(view1.column2)` be the right answer as opposed to `min(view1.column2)` ?

Comment: @APC this is a good point, if there are actual multiple values being returned, then the OP would need to determine *which* of them is the correct one to apply.  My point was that this error can (and does) occur *even when no duplicates are actually returned*, if during execution, Oracle cannot be *sure* that only one value per target row will be returned.  In that case, using `MAX()..GROUP BY..` provides a successful way to suppress this spurious error.

Answer (score 3):

For this example your problem is definitely in the USING subquery. This query produces more than one value of `table2.column1`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.column1, 
        view1.column2
 FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE_2 table2
 LEFT JOIN SCHEMA2.VIEW_1 view1
 ON table2.column2 = view1.column3
```

So the ON clause will match the same row(s) in `table1` more than once:

```
ON (table1.column3 = t2.column1 )
```

Oracle cannot figure out which value of `t2.column2` should be used in the UPDATE, so it hurls `ORA-30926`.

Using distinct in the subquery doesn't help because that gives permutations of all the columns. You need to write a subquery which will produce unique values of `t2.column1` across all rows, or add another identifying column(s) to generate a unique key you can join to `table1`.